# undefined index REMOTE ADDR when running newsletter cron.php

Tags: php

THIS IS MY LINE OF CODE IN APPKERNEL PHP

```
<?php
   use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;
   $tempuri = ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/');
   $tempuri = explode('/',$tempuri);
   if(strpos($tempuri[0],'~') !== false){
   $fixurlbase = "/{$tempuri[0]}/";
   }else{
   $fixurlbase = "/";
   }

/*** Composer ***/
include __DIR__ . "/../vendor/autoload.php";

/**** Debug ****/
if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] == "84.228.79.100" || $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == "82.81.17.192" 
|| $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == "82.81.40.186" || $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == "127.0.0.1"){
DEFINE("DEBUG",1);
}else{
 DEFINE("DEBUG",0);
}
```

I keep getting this error I don't know why I tried to run cron for a newsletter

this is the errors

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6gxk.png)

Comment: thi is the erro: Notice: Undefined index: REQUEST_URI in /home/yail/app/AppKernel.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR in /home/yail/app/AppKernel.php on line 17

Notice: Undefined index: REMOTE_ADDR in /home/yail/app/AppKernel.php on line 17

Comment: For a cron job, what would you expect the `REQUEST_URI` to be?